# EEGLab import .mat file

Tags: matlab, bandpass, eeg, multi-channel

I am new to EEG and signal processing, anyone can please check if I fill in the right numbers? I am confused about those terms.

For example, the recording using 22 EEG channels and 3 EOG channels, should I put 22 or 25 in the "Number of Channels"? Also, is the "Time points per epoch" equal to (seconds of motor imagination) * (sampling frequency)? I am so confused about each of the terms in the form...

[image: import form]

Also, this is the dataset description: [https://lampx.tugraz.at/~bci/database/001-2014/description.pdf](https://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ebci/database/001-2014/description.pdf)

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you need to as whoever wrote this specific software and/or read the documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about usage of a specific software package, not about signal processing.